# How to use Active-Directory to authenticate against a Mule ESB connector

Tags: active-directory, mule, kerberos

The Mule community documentation http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Authentication only refers to Basic, OAuth1 & OAuth2 authentication methods when connecting to an API endpoint. Is there an "out of the box" method to authenticate against an API end point using Active-Directory/Kerberos?

Answer (score 0):

Mule works fine with Spring Security, so you can configure authenticationManager bean with ldap.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+the+Spring+Security+Manager
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Setting+up+LDAP+Provider+for+Spring+Security